# preg_replace all numbers before underscore, than replace underscore and end

Tags: php, preg-replace

I would like to replace all numbers before the underscore, than replace underscore too and than end. Underscore should behave like "breakpoint".

I have strings with prefix, like:

```
0_xxxx
1_xxxx
2_xxxx
```

and I have to remove that prefix.

Could someone please provide a example?

Comment: Please provide an example of what text you have and what result you need to get.

Comment: Please share your input string on which you want to perform `preg_replace`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry, I've edited post, you can find it there now.

Comment: `$string = '123_HELLO';

list(,$restOfString) = sscanf($string, "%d_%s");
var_dump($restOfString);`

Comment: @MarkBaker if that is an answer, don't post it as a comment.

Comment: @mickmackusa - If it's short enough to fit within a tweet, I don't consider it worth an answer

Comment: @MarkBaker  This is a problem on SO.  People post answers as comments, the OP gets a solution and doesn't come back to SO.  Many, many questions go unresolved because of this.  It is simply not how Q&A is meant to flow.

Comment: @mickmackusa I guess I've been doing it wrong all these years; I'd better just give up then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to remove these prefixes using regexes.

```
echo preg_replace('/^\d+_/', '', '0_xxxx');
// Will output 'xxxx'
```

This example code will remove all numbers followed by an underscore from the start of your string.